# Show all elements from 45 list live on one list

Tags: list

How could show elements from 45 list in one list live, without any wait. How Could  I view this records from 45 lists in one screen ?

Comment: The list are situated in many sites.

Answer (score 2):

My choice would be to create a result source in SharePoint search. See: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj683115.aspx. The small downside is that you need to wait for the search crawl to index the items.

Other options would be to call all the rest api's for all the lists. Performance wise this is probably not a good solution.